# vagrant triggers not as straightforward as they seem

Tags: vagrant

so i'm a little confused about the lifecycle of the triggers

```
box.trigger.after :up do

  puts "test after up"

  if File.file?('./.vagrant/status')

    puts "status file already created"

  else

    puts "will create status file"

  end

  File.open('./.vagrant/status', "w+") { |file| file.write("up") } unless File.file?('./.vagrant/status')

end

box.trigger.before :destroy do

    puts "test before destroy"

end
```

i'm testing to see when code is run depending on the lifecycle of each triggered event.

running `vagrant up` or `vagrant down` will run thru and execute both blocks.

I'll see all `puts` statements regardless of the `vagrant` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled on the same issue, and eventually figured out that triggers are only enabled when the triggers plugin has been installed:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

Hope this helps!